# Django Framework got Server Error 500 when DEBUG to False

Tags: django, server, render, server-side-rendering, http-status-code-500

I am using Django framework for project. I am rendering the HTML templet

```
def index(request):
    print(" --- check fine?")            # for print debug
    trees = Tree.objects.all()
    print(trees)
    return render(request, "index.html", {'trees': trees})
```

```
 --- check fine?
<QuerySet [<Tree: Tree object (8)>, <Tree: Tree object (10)>, <Tree: Tree object (11)>, <Tree: Tree object (12)>]>
[06/Feb/2021 17:28:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145
```

these are my urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
     path("", views.index, name="index"),
     path('about/', views.about , name='about'),
     path('contact/', views.contact , name='contact'),
     path('upload/', views.upload_file , name='upload'),
    ]
```

`DEBUG = False`  I am getting above error.

when I set my
`DEBUG = True` every thing works fine means show index.html and shows even data too.

setting  `DEBUG = False` make difficult to find an error.

index.html contains below code which fetches data.

```
{% for tree in trees %}
    <article class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 tm-gallery-item">
        <figure>
            <img src="{{tree.image.url}}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid tm-gallery-img" />
                <figcaption>
                    <h4 class="tm-gallery-title">{{tree.name}}</h4>
                    <p class="tm-gallery-description">{{tree.desc}}</p>
                    <!-- <p class="tm-gallery-price"></p> -->
                </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

and allowed hosts are.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*','127.0.0.1','localhost']
```

Comment: You are likely getting 500 error because of the static / media files. When you set `DEBUG = False` it means you are using a production server. Django does not serve static / media files in production (inefficient). Check [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: issue is solved. problem was I am trying to access using STATICFILES_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

1. Django returns an HTTP status code of 500, an Internal Server Error, when Django encounters runtime errors in a view, such as a syntax error or a view failing to return an object that Django expects. Closely related to errors in view logic is that Django itself will raise the TemplateDoesNotExist exception when an error is encountered in a view, the DEBUG setting is set to False, and a 500.html template is not found.
2. Beginning with Django 1.5 a new “allowed hosts” setting was introduced. When DEBUG is set to False, it is enforced. In your settings.py file, find the that looks like:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
and change it to include the Droplet’s IP address and/or the domain name pointing to your site. For example:

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["example.com", "111.111.111.111"]

Source:

1. [https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/troubleshooting.html#:~:text=Django%20returns%20an%20HTTP%20status,an%20object%20that%20Django%20expects](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/troubleshooting.html#:%7E:text=Django%20returns%20an%20HTTP%20status,an%20object%20that%20Django%20expects).
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/server-error-500-django-digital-ocean

Answer (score 0):

This are varible from settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    
]
MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"
```

due to `STATICFILES_STORAGE`  `collectstatic` were using whitenoise engine. I comment `STATICFILES_STORAGE` .
I suggest to delete all `STATIC_ROOT` directry in above case /staticfiles folder.

and use
`python manage.py collectstatic`
to collect files.

and use this in url

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('ourhouse.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls'))
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

to use static and media files.